# When running `grub-install /dev/sdb` I get the error: ls: /dev/sdb/proc: Not a directory

Tags: linux, debian, grub

I'm running the Debian 12 bookworm installer (debian-12.4.0-amd64-netinst.iso) and trying to install with GRUB and MBR because the UEFI support from my motherboard seems to be limited (I couldn't make it work).

During the install I say to install GRUB on /dev/sdb (which is the best drive to use, it's a spinning rust SATA drive) but then I get the error shown in the picture below.

If I run the command manually from another TTY like this:

`grub-installer /dev/sdb`

it clears the screen, prints the following message, and exits with error level 1.

`ls: /dev/sdb/proc: Not a directory`

It seems to me that for some reason the GRUB installer is using the `ls` command with a path of `/dev/sdb/proc` but I don't understand why it would be doing that?

Have I found a bug in the GRUB installer? What can I do to proceed?

[image: GRUB install fatal error]